# How to bind to a broadcast address in Micrium

Tags: micrium

I'm trying to find a way to bind an IPv4 UDP socket to a broadcast address in Micrium (µC/OS-Ⅲ).

Attempt to bind a socket to the actual broadcast address just returns `NET_SOCK_ERR_INVALID_ADDR`. The broadcast is not explicitly mentioned on the list of things to bind on the `NetSock_Bind` call documentation, there is no analogue of `SO_BROADCAST` either. Is it impossible at all?

Can I, as a last resort, add a broadcast address to an existing interface as its own address (this shouldn't mess up ARP, since nobody is going to ask for it, and I'm not going to send anything through it)?

Comment: I'm trying to use it now as well, did you find anything?
BTW, you can use multicast address and work with the multicast implementation (which they have documentation of).

Answer (score 0):

look at [micrium documentation](https://doc.micrium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10750603).
Follow the steps and you'll get no error.

BTW, if you won't use `NetApp_SetSockAddr`and try to bind using `NetSock_Bind`, you'll receive the `NET_SOCK_ERR_INVALID_ADDR` which happened to you.

**Edit:**

look at the next code, which works for me.
Note that the IP Address I manually initialized the host's address and used the defined address `NET_SOCK_ADDR_IP_V4_WILDCARD`.

```
NET_SOCK_ADDR_IPv4 host;
NET_ERR perr;

Mem_Clr(&host, sizeof(host));
host.AddrFamily = NET_SOCK_ADDR_FAMILY_IP_V4;
host.Addr = NET_UTIL_HOST_TO_NET_32(NET_SOCK_ADDR_IP_V4_WILDCARD);
host.Port = NET_UTIL_HOST_TO_NET_16(socketPort);

netSockId = NetSock_Open( NET_SOCK_PROTOCOL_FAMILY_IP_V4, 
                          NET_SOCK_TYPE_DATAGRAM,
                          NET_SOCK_PROTOCOL_UDP,
                         &perr);

if (perr != NET_SOCK_ERR_NONE)
{
    // log the error.
    return;
}

NetSock_Bind(                 netSockId,
             (NET_SOCK_ADDR*)&host,
                              NET_SOCK_ADDR_SIZE,
                             &perr);
if (perr != NET_SOCK_ERR_NONE)
{
    // log the error.
    return;
}
```

What I said about the `NetApp_SetSockAddr()` function, is that if I call it instead of manually initializing the host, it returned the error you received.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see anything on that particular page that talks about broadcast. Binding to regular addresses works just fine for UDP sockets without calling `NetApp_SetSockAddr`.

Comment: @PawelVeselov I edited the answer so it would show my code

Comment: Are you saying that binding to NET_SOCK_ADDR_IP_V4_WILDCARD will make the socket receive broadcast packets?

Comment: @PawelVeselov yes